# Postgres convert timestamp with timezone to date

Tags: postgresql, date, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a postgres database, that stores some accounting data.
The accounting data have a timestamp (with timezone).

I would like to aggregate/group the accounting data by date.
But the date should be in the user's/requested timezone not UTC.

```sql
SELECT '2023-08-01'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'; -- 2023-07-31 22:00:00+00
```

Outputs the correct UTC value for the timestamp,

but if I cast that to date then it returns the UTC date:

```sql
SELECT date('2023-08-01'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'); -- 2023-07-31
```

Is there a way to output the date in Europe/Berlin time? (`2023-08-01`)

Comment: What does `show timezone;` return?

Comment: It shows `UTC`.

Comment: Per @LaurenzAlbe answer change to `SELECT date('2023-08-01'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'); 2023-08-01`.

Comment: `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` fixes the issue as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that a `timestamp with time zone` field doesn't actually store the time zone.   So users with different time zone settings will get different dates back with that approach.  For this reason, often it's useful to store an additional field that is a `date` type for the date relevant to the business logic, along side the timestamp.  Especially for accounting - you probably don't want end-of-month dates being treated as start-of-month dates in other time zones.

Comment: Should I store my timestamps as timestamps with or without timezone then? (Even if it actually doesn't in both of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `timestamp with time zone`, you can get the current date in Germany at that time with

```
SELECT date(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin');
```

Your example uses a `timestamp without time zone`, which may be the problem.

Comment: This answer is confusing me. `current_timestamp` is a different value than the one I can pass to the query. FFR: `SELECT '2023-08-01'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'`

Comment: But you said that the data type in the PostgreSQL table is `timestamp with time zone`, so I used `current_timestamp` as a substitute. All your examples show a `timestamp without time zone` which behaves quite differently. Perhaps you can add some detail to the question to add clarity.

Comment: I think I confused myself here quite a bit, because the `::timestamp AT TIME ZONE` part produces a timestamp with timezone, but `timestamptz AT TIME ZONE` produces a timestamp without timezone. date(timestamp) produces the date in the default/selected timezone which is UTC and not the passed timezone of the value.
I'll probably have to use both approaches, one for filters passed by users, the other for the grouping of the in table data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it

```
    SELECT (timestamp '2023-08-01' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin')::date;

To apply it on your accounting data, use this

    SELECT
        (myTimeStampColumnName AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin')::date
        FROM
        my_accounting_table_name;

Please change `myTimeStampColumnName` with your actual Attribute Name holding the `TimeStamp` data and `my_accounting_table_name` with the actual Table Name of the parent `myTimeStampColumnName`.
```

In order to Group/Sum, use this approach

```
SELECT
    (myTimeStampColumnName AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin')::date AS europe_berlin_date,
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM
    my_accounting_table_name
GROUP BY
    (myTimeStampColumnName AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin')::date;
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.